# Windows 2012 R2 causes WMI Failures after install of Directory Sync Tool from Office 365

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, microsoft-office-365

After installing Office 365 AD sync as referenced on Office 365, you may run into WMI errors on your server along with a ton of other errors.  This issue has been driving me nuts on multiple client servers over the past couple of weeks.  They can include error 1603 on install, errors installing SQL Server Express, errors installing Microsoft Sign-In Assistant and more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is actually extremely simple.  Use Azure Active Directory Sync a new tool from Microsoft ([https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect/](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect/%20%22Active%20Directory%20Sync))

By using this the problems will go away and it will sync directly with Office 365 no problem.  Do not use the guide located in Office 365.